# Create distribution profile from .p12 certificate iOS

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, p12

I have received a .p12 certificate from my Client. I have installed it to my KeyChain. I need to create a distribution provisioning using this and sign my app ipa with it.

How can I create the distribution profile using this information? Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8582198/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: Do you have access to Apple developer portal?  To create the distribution profile, your access level should be of either admin or agent. check this: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: @Imad I do not have access to the client apple account. I have my personal one though.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Thanks for the comment. I know how to sign the ipa by creating a new certificate from KeyChain and uploading it to the developer account to create a new provisioning profile. I need to know how to work with the .p12 certificate provided by the client to create a new provisioning profile

Comment: @user3034944 You need to have the access, ask your client to give admin access to your account. Guide him using this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html

Comment: @Imad is correct, you cannot create a profile from the certificate alone.  You need to create the provisioning profile referencing the certificate on Apple's developer site.  If the client is willing to send you the cert and private key, simply tell them to send you the distribution profile as well.  If they haven't created on, it is very easy to do (easier than creating a signing certificate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a distribution profile from a certificate and private key.  The provisioning profiles are created on Apple's developer site and must reference one or more certificate to be used with the profile.

You will need to either need to have the account owner create / download the profile from the developer site and send it to you, or grant you access as an admin on their team.  Also, before you request the iOS distribution profile from your client, make sure you also check that the .p12 file that was sent contains the certificate **and** the private key for the cert.  Without the private key, you won't be able to sign, even if you get the profile.

The 4 key pieces of code signing for iOS are the certificate, the **private key** for the **certificate**, the **provisioning profile**, and the **entitlements**.  If you are missing any of these, or if they are out of sync, you will run into problems. The private key is exactly what it says - **private**.  Apple does not have, nor does it want to store the private key.  That is kept by the app owner.  Apple will generate and allow you to download your certificate based off that private key (you share with them a cert signing request to generate the cert off of your key).  Similarly, you can generate / download existing provisioning profiles from Apple's dev site.  Finally, the entitlements in your app must match the entitlements granted on your profile. Those are assigned to your app, and the application's project settings requests access to services - this much match what is requested as part of the app ID / profile on Apple's dev site.  So those are the key components; from your question, hopefully you can get your client to send you the provisioning profile.  Also, you could potentially run into problems with out of sync entitements, if you need to do anything with additional services, like iCloud, if the client hasn't configured those properly for you.